# Child record's record type based on Parent record's record type

Tags: apex, record-type, related-list, master-detail

Objects: Account, Opportunity

Record Types: Account --> A, B
Record Types: Opportunity --> a, b

When creating an Opportunity I'm trying to setup an opportunity record type/page layout that will automatically be applied based on the Account record type chosen. My users already choose from a drop down with creating an account, so I don't want them to have to do it again when creating an opportunity. it should just be assigned based off the account record type choosen

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?  Are you using Classic or Lightning?

Comment: @DavidCheng I have tried the process builder but I'm a bit dubious how can I make that process builder to run in a custom button

Comment: You can't make a PB run in a custom button. The PB runs when the record is updated or created so in your case you would create the record, probably with the wrong record type, and the PB would run and "fix" the record type after the record is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few things to consider

### Validation Rule

Possibly the simplest solution is to create a validation rule that prevents users from creating records with the wrong record type

```
RecordType.Name != Contact__c.RecordType.Name
```

This would throw an error telling them they selected the wrong type and force them to go back to fix the mistake. While not entirely user friendly this is a fast and easy approach.

### Trigger/PB

You could set up a trigger or PB that automatically sets the record type when the record is created. This way it doesn't matter what record type the end user selects, the automation will override it.

The drawback here being you lose control over what fields are displayed while the record is being created (to an extent anyway).

### Visualfoce

Remove the new button and create a  button that takes the user to a custom VF page where you can completely customize the experience. on page load check the record type and load a field set with a matching name to determine what fields to display for editing.

This option is probably one of the most complicated but also the most flexible.

### Custom Buttons (Classic only)

One of the things my company does (for better or worse) Is they removed the standard new button from the related list and created a custom "new" button for each record type. This uses URL hacking to set the record type by default on the new page.

```
/<prefix such as 005>/e?retURL=%2F{!Record.Id}&parentid={!Record.Id}&Name={!TRIM(Record.Name)}&RecordType=<XXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

- The prefix should be the 3 letter prefix of the desired objects ID
- The record ID is the id of the parent related record, in your case it'd be contact
- The ID of the desired record type

This completely by passes the page where you select the record type and forces the record to the type that you want.

### VisualFlow

You can create a button that links to a visual flow that creates a wizard-like experience for creating the child record. The flow could run a query on the parent to get the record type name and attempt to set the record type automatically.

### Lightning

You could create a component that aids in creating the child record and add the component as an action to the publisher (or anywhere on the page you could normally ad a component).

### Quick Action?

I'm not sure how dynamically you can set the default values of fields in quick actions but this is just another area you could look at. This approach is similar to the custom buttons in that you may need more than one.

Comment: Woww thanks very much man! I'll try one of these. Looks VisualFlow might be the solution for me.

Comment: I'm trying the URL hack with custom buttons but I have conditions like if Contact record's record type is 'A' --> Custom object record type should be 'A.1', if Contact record's record type is 'B' --> Custom object record type should be 'B.1' and so on.. Is it possible with the custom button URL hack?

Comment: Yes it's possible if you absolutely need to do it in a single button. The custom button URL field is a formula field so you can put if statements. You'll have to do something like `IF(recordType.name = '', 'recordTypeId', if(recordType.name='','recordType2Id', <else else else>))`